Avoid multiple qmldir files in subfolders
My project structure:
root_folder/
│
├── main.py
├── main.qml
├── qmldir
│
├── qml/
│   ├── app.qml
│   ├── qmldir
│   │
│   ├── pages/
│   │   ├── page1.qml
│   │   ├── page2.qml
│   │   └── qmldir
│   │
│   └── components/
│       ├── component1.qml
│       ├── component2.qml
│       └── qmldir
│
└── py/

main.qml instantiates app.qml which then instantiates many components and subpages.
To make them easily accessible to each other I have created various qmldir files but... this seems to be really, really bad. Anytime I decide to add a qml file, I have to append it to each qmldir file that might need it.
So what I'm thinking is one of the two:

somehow condense qmldir files to one so its easier to manage.
forget qmldir and switch to relative imports inside qml files.

Is former possible? or is there a better way?

I don't think there is anything that would generate qmldir automatically in PySide, but you can write a script for it.

@smr If I'd have to write a script then I'm not doing this right. Should I stick to relative imports then?

If your only problem is appending file names into a single qmldir file, then I don't know. I think using a qmldir file is best practice, since adding new files only happens occasionally, so it shouldn't be that annoying.
